# how to remove sensitivity of arduino for analog reading?

Tags: arduino, current-measurement

I am using Arduino UNO i want to read watts of led which is connected with 9v source battery and  and  i am using current sensor module for reading Watts
but arduino gives me some values in analog reading if i dont event attached my led how can i remove it extra value and find accurate value of led ?

Comment: show readings on schematic

Comment: Calibrate ADC with a reference voltage for 0 mid point and max input for gain and offset errors.  If adding Op AMps , observe common mode input range.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Arduino UNO i want to read watts of led

A "current sensor" measures current in amps (or milli amps). Watts (power) is that current multiplied by voltage across the device. If the Arduino gives a value that should be zero but isn't then maybe this is because at zero amps the numerical value is halfway in the range of the analogue-to-digital converter it uses.

This would allow it to "read" or measure amps that are both positive in value and negative in value (useful for when measuring alternating currents).

You may need to offset the current reading with half the numerical scale of the full-scale-range of your ADC to accommodate this.

There can be other errors too and notably just a simple mid-range offset or imperfect conversion gain can account for what might seem sizable errors.